# WebRTC - How to mute local audio output

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to mute only the local audio playback in WebRTC, more specifically after getUserMedia() and prior to any server connection being made. None of the options I've found work; this one from Muaz Khan fails:

```
var audioTracks = localMediaStream.getAudioTracks();
// if MediaStream has reference to microphone
if (audioTracks[0]) {
    audioTracks[0].enabled = false;
}
```

[source](http://muaz-khan.blogspot.com/2014/05/webrtc-tips-tricks.html)

This technique is also [described here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114163) as "working", but fails here on Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit) (Ubuntu 14.04).

Additional method that is said to work by using volume gain:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(clientStream);
var volume = audioContext.createGain();
source.connect(volume);
volume.connect(audioContext.destination);
volume.gain.value = 0;  //turn off the speakers
```

tl;dr I don't want to hear the input from my microphone on my speakers, but I do want to see my video image.

**Workaround**

This workaround was suggested by [Benjamin Trent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1818849/benjamin-trent) and it mutes the audio by setting the muted attribute on the video tag like so:

```
document.getElementById("html5vid").muted = true;
```

[Also similar question, but its for video, so not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804667/webrtc-getusermedia-how-to-properly-mute-local-video)

Comment: Why not set the html video tag to muted?

Comment: That's not ideal in my case, but is audio "only" mute supported on the tag?

Comment: muting the video html tag mutes the audio associated with the video. The video will continue to play and both audio and video tracks in the stream will still be accessible and able to be sent to another peer. It sounds like, though, you found a bug in that Chrome release on ubuntu that does need to be addressed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Adding this as the answer because it is the de facto correct answer:

What you stated as a workaround is what's used by many major WebRTC Video platforms:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    const vid = document.getElementById('html5vid');
    vid.autoplay = true;
    vid.muted = true;
    vid.srcObject = stream;
  });
```

Comment: What about audio recording only, like { video: false, audio: true }?

Comment: @headkit just don't attach your own audio to the DOM at all. To indicate to the user that audio is being captured you can show a waveform or speaking indicator.

Comment: Hi @xdumaine, what I did was, I instantiate the `new Audio()` on javascript. Is it still possible to mute while streaming the data being played from that?