# WebRTC how to mute local audio playback in Android?

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm creating a basic WebRTC application for Android, so far most of the things works just fine, except for the audio. Whenever the the connection is established, there's a really loud and echoing noise, which doesn't stop until the connection ends. I have looked into some similar problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908408/webrtc-how-to-mute-local-audio-output), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249144/echo-and-noise-in-sound-webrtc-android), which suggested something like enabling echo cancellation and disabling local audio playback.

Now, the problem is I can't find any way to disable the local audio playback on Android, is this still something that's controllable on Android?

Comment: Are you developing on Android SDK or Android NDK? Are you using any third party Live streaming SDK?

Comment: Android SDK, no third party SDKs.

Comment: AFAIK, the Android SDK does not have WebRTC in it, other than to the extent you load WebRTC stuff into a `WebView`. You might want to check out existing open source WebRTC apps for Android, such as [Riot.im](https://github.com/vector-im/riot-android), and see how they are implementing WebRTC, whether they seem to suffer from the same audio problems, etc.

Comment: It's not in the Android SDK, but there's a WebRTC native API, and that's what I'd like to use to control the audio and other stuff. But I'll check out the other examples.